# Two versions of rack in Gemfile.lock causing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, passenger, rack

Rails app runs fine locally but on the remote server I get this error:

> You have already activated rack 1.4.1, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.4.4. Using bundle exec may solve this.

I've `bundle update`-ed several times.

My Gemfile.lock has these lines (`...` indicates removed lines for clarity):

```
...
actionpack (3.2.11)
  ...
  rack (~> 1.4.0)
...
rack (1.4.4)
...
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem "haml"
gem 'execjs'
gem "rest-client"
gem "stripe"

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.2.4"
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  # Deploy with Capistrano
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'rvm-capistrano'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

group :production do
  gem 'libv8'
  gem 'therubyracer', "~> 0.10.2"
  gem "newrelic_rpm"
  gem 'exception_notification', git: 'git://github.com/alanjds/exception_notification.git', :require => 'exception_notifier'
end

gem 'sqlite3' # This has to be active in both modes

group :development do
  gem "thin"
end

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end
```

Comment: Hi, are you sure that the file you've posted is the only Gemfile out there. Try to search "Gemfile" inside your project's subfolders. Gemfile.lock just collects and combines different Gemfiles from the root and its subfolders (i.e. redmine plugins)

Comment: `find . -name Gemfile` gets only one result, this one.

Comment: Try to delete Gemfile.lock and run bundler install again

Comment: Thanks -- did that already. Same issue.

Comment: what about gem install rack 1.4.4? you can do it by running  gem install rack --version '= 1.4.4' or the same instruction just prepend bundler exec to gem install... p.s. corrected the version

Comment: Locally or on the server? I'm deploying using Capistrano.

Comment: on the server. just as you did with bundler update (cd to the application root). oh and you might have to install gem package on whatever distro you are using.

Comment: I don't think that's it. The problem isn't that Rack 1.4.4 isn't found, it's that Rack 1.4.1 is being activated first. I tried it anyway and still the same error message. Appreciate your suggestions, though!

Comment: and what about removing rack v1.4.1? In my understanding both rack version requests will be satisfied by 1.4.4. anyway have you already tried to modify Gemfile.lock, I'm not sure about it, but it should not be updated by bundler install instruction. I know it's not a real solutiona and it's not future-proof, but you could just try to do so and see what happens. p.s. whe should move to the chat

Comment: Thanks for your help, Salaros, you get an upvote for your patience. I figured it out (see below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working, so I'll post it here. This is what I had to do:

1. Run `gem uninstall rack` locally and remove all instances of rack
2. Add `gem "rack", "1.4.1"` to my Gemfile (note this is the one it said it already loaded)
3. Run `bundle update` locally
4. Deploy

Now it works!